# Class property error VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I am getting runtine error 91: Object vriable or With block variable not set whne I run a simple class manipulation code.

Here are my classes

cTask:

```
Private pMile As cMile

Public Property Get Mile() As cMile
    Set Mile = pMile
End Property

Public Property Set Mile(Value As cMile)
    Set pMile = Value
End Property

Private Sub Class_Initializer()
    Set Me.Mile = New cMile
End Sub
```

cMile:

```
Private pstatus As String

Public Property Get status() As String
    status = ppstatus
End Property

Public Property Let status(Value As String)
    pstatus = Value
End Property
```

And the sub:

```
Sub testt()

    Dim ct As New cTasks

    ct.Mile.status = "compl"

    Debug.Print ct.Mile, ct.Mile.status

End Sub
```

The code goes from the sub to the get property in cTask. When about to execute the "End Propety" line the error pops up.

I guess something must be wrong with my classes but I don not know what. I have just recently started using classes. Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: `Debug.Print ct.Mile` won't work, it's like you want to print `Workheets.Name`.  You have to specify which worksheet `Workheets(1).Name`.  And for that, `Worksheets` must be a collection of worksheets so probably `Mile` should be too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo:

```
Class_Initializer()
```

should be

```
Class_Initialize()
```

This prevents `ct`'s `Mile` from being created so accessing it raises the error you see.

`ppstatus` is also spelt incorrectly.

Comment: but can I set different classes cMile for one given ct and then multiple properties status for each?

Comment: My question I guess is how do I reinitialise a new cMile class in cTask without and how do I name it in the sub without losing the other cMile?

Comment: I don't follow, if you make the corrections ct.Mile should work fine